# how exactly does OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad work?

Tags: java, groovy

According to the oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html), method getSystemCpuLoad:

> getSystemCpuLoad()
> Returns the "recent cpu usage" for the **whole system.**

And when i try to grab cpu usage metrics, i always see low values (something like 1-2%), but I know that the system is currently loaded (50%+).

```
static double getSystemCPUUsage(OperatingSystemMXBean os) {
    return ((com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) os).getSystemCpuLoad() * 100.0
}
```

Question: which exactly cpu usage returning this method?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How do you know it's loaded more than 50%?

Comment: before taking the metrics I load the system